# How do I capture a screenshot of an iPad app that has a lot of HORIZONTAL scroll?

Tags: ipad

I have an app that has a lot of product information that scrolls horizontally.

Note: I tried an app called Web Capture but it requires a URL and only scrolls vertically.

Comment: You could click two or more screenshots and attach them manually!

Answer (score 3):

Take screenshots each page, then combine them together in an app like Photoshop where the extra UI can be removed from each intermediate image. There's no automated way of doing this on the device.